# Loading img src="" with url from MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have saved the url of an image in my database and now need to pull that image out and display it.

Right now I've tried this but the image does not show

```
<td id="cell_1" width="85" height="85">
   <?php
      $queryRole = "SELECT roleimg FROM mixotype WHERE email = :email";

          $stmt = $db->prepare($queryRole);
          $stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);
          $stmt->execute();

          while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
         {
             ?><img src="<?php $row['roleimg']?>  width='85' height='85'  />"<?php
         }
   ?>
</td>
```

Am i trying going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am sure I'm not going mad! You've just missed the echo out!?

```
<img src="<?php $row['roleimg']?> width='85' height='85'  />
```

To read:

```
<img src="<?php echo $row['roleimg']; ?>" width='85' height='85'  />
```

Mike.

Comment: And the quotes closing the `src` of the image.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
     {
         ?><img src="<?php $row['roleimg']?>  width='85' height='85'  />"<?php
     }
```

to

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
     {
         ?><img src="<?php echo $row['roleimg'];?>"  width='85' height='85'  />"<?php
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed the quotes on your `src` in the file, you are also using poorly written code (not even sure if it would work as is: Try changing it to:

```
<img src="<?php echo $row['roleimg'];?>"  width='85' height='85'  />
```

Answer (score 0):

You accidently put your closing quotation marks at the end of the img tag instead of after the echo'd src.

```
?><img src="<?php $row['roleimg']?>  width='85' height='85'  />"<?php
```

should be

```
?><img src="<?php echo $row['roleimg']; ?>"  width='85' height='85'  /><?php
```

An easy mistake to make, but it's also one should you should see instantly if you take the time to troubleshoot with some basic tools (ie look at the HTML this script generates).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to end the double quotes on **src** attribute.

Comment: Double quotes, sorry :D

Comment: Well, it made me laugh at least :)

Comment: It is just a quote `"`. Double quotes are 2 quotes `""`. And this little bastard, `'`, is called an apostrophe.

Comment: I'm glad it did. I'm not an english native speaker :D

Comment: Maybe I should write in code instead of trying to explain in words, I express better this way :D

Answer (score 0):

Change `"<?php $row['roleimg']?>` into `"<?php echo $row['roleimg']; ?>"`

Comment: @SeanHall in stead of kissing me, consider +1 the answer and/or accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You miss the echo tag. and if that doesnt help you could try to put base64_encode around it and  put this in front : data:image/png;base64 . This makes the chance on error from the browser or the http headers a lot smaller.

But i think you should put the image into a different file and load it from that file, since it will cache the images, and will make you use a lot less data bandwith. So you could use image.php?imgid=....